# Sensor fusion with compass and gyroscope: between 0 and 360 degrees

Tags: ios, sensors, gyroscope, fusion, magnetometer

I'm developing a small indoor navigation app in which I use the gyro and the compass for the device orientation. I use the gyro to smooth the compass data. My sensor fusion looks like the following. This is my motionHandler where everything happens.

```
// Listen to events from the motionManager
motionHandler = ^ (CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {

        __block float heading;
        heading = mHeading;

        CMAttitude *currentAttitude = motion.attitude;

        //Initial heading setting
        if (lastHeading == 0 && heading != 0) {
            updatedHeading = heading;
        }
        lastHeading = heading;

        if (oldQuaternion.w != 0 || oldQuaternion.x != 0 || oldQuaternion.y != 0 || oldQuaternion.z != 0){
            diffQuaternion = [self multiplyQuaternions:[self inverseQuaternion:oldQuaternion] :currentAttitude.quaternion];
            diffQuaternion = [self normalizeQuaternion:diffQuaternion];
        }            
        oldQuaternion = currentAttitude.quaternion;

        diffYaw = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES([self yawFromQuaternion:diffQuaternion]);         

        quaternion = currentAttitude.quaternion;

        //Get Pitch
        rpy.pitch = -[self pitchFromQuaternion:quaternion];
        rpy.pitch += M_PI/2;                        

        //Use Yaw-Difference for Heading
        updatedHeading = updatedHeading - diffYaw;

        //Heading has to be between 0 and 360 degrees
        if (updatedHeading < 0) {
            updatedHeading = 360 + updatedHeading;
        }
        else if (updatedHeading > 360) {
            updatedHeading -= 360;
        }

        //fusionate gyro estimated heading with new magneticHeading
        updatedHeading = (19.0*updatedHeading + 1.0*heading)/20.0;

        //generate queternion
        rotation = [self createFromAxisAngle:0 :rpy.pitch :DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(updatedHeading)];
    };
```

The actual sensor fusion formula is this line: `updatedHeading = (19.0*updatedHeading + 1.0*heading)/20.0;`.
And this is my didUpdateHeading-function which receives the newest heading-information:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    // Get new heading
    mHeading = newHeading.magneticHeading;    

    mHeading += 90;

    if (mHeading > 360) {
        mHeading -= 360;
    }
}
```

`diffYaw` is the change of the heading computed by the gyroscope. `rotation` ist the final quaternion.
This works perfect, except one particular case: at the transition between 0 und 360 degrees.

If `updatedHeading` is near to but smaller than 360 and `mHeading` is just above 0 the result moves in a circle. For example if `updatedHeading` = 355 and `mHeading` = 5, the correct result should be between 360 and 5. But my formula computes 337,5 degrees, which is clearly completly wrong!

There have to be any common workarounds for this problem, I think…

Comment: Is there nobody who could help? :-/

Comment: I just wonder, does your program also track your movement. I mean not just rotation, but also translation of the divide, when you just walk. Is combination of gyro and magnetometer capable of tracking the complicated movement of the device in 3D space?

Comment: Is there any reason why you operate directly on the quarternion? It seems -[CMAttitude multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:] might simplify your code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like the following in these types of angle computations:

```
updatedHeading -= angleDiff(updatedHeading, mHeading) * 0.05;
```

where angleDiff() is:

```
double angleDiff( double angle1, double angle2 )
{
    double angle = angle1 - angle2;
    if( angle > 180 ) {
        angle -= 360;
    } else if( angle <= -180 ) {
        angle += 360;
    }
    return angle;
}
```

You may want to get updatedHeading back in the 0-360 range after this by:

```
updatedHeading = fmod( updatedHeading + 360, 360 );
```

Your example gives 355.5 with this computation.